# Apache Camel concatenates address rest with redirect address

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel for system integration and I'm having a strange url linkage problem that only occurs with these conditions:

- I expose a REST service that provides parameters
- I do not use the Processor for data transformation but the beans

I use Apache Camel with Spring Boot and the *netty4-http* component for redirects. Below is a simplified example that creates the anomaly:

```
@Component
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
     public void configure() throws Exception {
     getContext().getGlobalOptions().put("CamelJacksonEnableTypeConverter", "true");

                restConfiguration()
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port("8096")
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

                 rest()
                    .get("/method/{param1}")    
                    // Same problem if i use from() instead route()
                    .route()    
                        .to("direct:some-operation")
                        .to("netty4-http://localhost:8080/another/service"); 
        }
    }


    @Component
    public class TestBean {

        @Consume(uri = "direct:some-operation")
        public String getStartProcess() {
            /* bean's operation */
            return "Hello";
        }

    }
```

For example, if I call http://localhost:8096/method/dog, the result I get is that the call is redirected to http://localhost:8080/another/service/method/dog, which is redirect and rest are concatenated.

The first attempt I made was to remove the *to()* bean, thinking it was what created the problem, but the result did not change.

So I did so many tests and I noticed that the anomaly does not occur if I do one of these operations:

- instead of using the bean, I move the the logic to the process. In
  this way I create a new *message out* in the exchange object and
  the redirect is correct (at least it's the explanation I gave myself)

  ```
  .process(new Processor() {

      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception{
          /* same bean's operation */
          exchange.getOut().setBody("Hello");

      }
  }).to("netty4-http://localhost:8080/another/service");
  ```
- If I expose the REST call without parameters, then as .get ("/ method"), it also works with the bean and no concatenation takes place

Why do I have this behaviorally anomalous? 
Is there a possible solution with the use of the bean?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already try to reset/delete the Exchange.HTTP_URI  and/or Exchange.HTTP_PATH header, between the get(...) and the to(...) ?

Comment: No, I had not tried. I did it now and it only works by removing HTTP_PATH. If I remove HTTP_URI, the problem remains. Thank you, problem solved!

However, from some research, I noticed that for the rest many recommend the restlet component and in fact, if I add it, the calls work even without this remove. Do you know what the difference is between using it and not? Is it possible that the component does this "cleaning" automatically? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

```
 from("direct-vm:consumeWs")
            .routeId("all-service-consume")
            .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
            .removeHeader("CamelHttp*")
```